# What parts of Java do I need to learn for specific software projects?

Tags: java, learning, android, gui

I'm starting a 12 week Java course next month through my local junior college. I'm starting from square 1. I have a basic understanding of OO and Java will be my first OO language. My Google-Fu returns way too much and I can't tell which is good, bad, etc.

As far as learning the language, is it best to use a plain editor, I use JEdit currently, or an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans? I don't have experience with either IDE. Is there other IDEs I should consider?

My project goals are:

- GUI programs to control different radios and test equipment, which means I/O via USB, sound card, and networking across *NIX, Windows, and Mac OS.
- Programming for Android devices, both phone and tablets. Database backed apps for logging data. Quite possibly accessing radio/test gear over WiFi.
- JBoss environment.

How should I setup a testing environment for different platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's my suggestions:

**Get an IDE** - in practice, most Java developers use an IDE nowadays and it will help you considerably with things like syntax checking, testing and debugging. I personally use the "Eclipse IDE for Java developers" which has served me very well. You can [download Eclipse here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). I also hear good things about Netbeans and IntelliJ - I don't think you could go wrong with any of these. Make sure you can create an run a simple "Hello World" application from scratch in your chosen IDE.

**Do the Java tutorials** - these are [great tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) that take you through many of the basics. I'd honestly recommend doing all of these (and learning how best to use your chosen IDE as you go along).

**Pick an area to focus on**. Even after you've mastered all the basics, you can't expect to become a expert at every advanced topic all at once. You might, for example, decide to focus on learning [Android](http://www.android.com/) first. You'll be writing Java as before, but many of the APIs and tools are Android specific and you will need to learn them. Make sure that you actually *build things that work* - it's the best way to learn how to code in any language.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to run from console and plain-text editor for getting started, Once you understand packages/imports, how to run, building using console (Command line).

Then you can pickup Netbeans/Eclipse, based on your choice. I suggest you use Eclipse first, after that you can try Netbeans, and use whichever you find suitable to you.